# MacOS OSX How to change the text to speech voice in terminal or with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, terminal, accessibility, text-to-speech, macos-sierra

I'm looking for a way to change the voice with a shortcut:
going in to settings->accessibility->Speech and setting the voice "Alex"
take's to long.

Does anyone know a terminal command? Or a way to change it with a keyboard shortcut?

I use speech in English and in Dutch so i have to manually change the voice a couple of times a day. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/mklement0/voices. Voices is a command line tool for changing the default text-to-speech voice. But the author of the tool warns that:

> As of macOS 10.12 (Sierra), there is no documented programmatic way to
>   change the default voice. Thus, this utility makes use of undocumented
>   system internals, which, unfortunately, means that future
>   compatibility of this feature is uncertain.

But at the moment, it seems to work with the latest Sierra version.

In addition, the author also provides links to alternatives, like:

> If you have Alfred with its Power Pack, consider workflow speak.awf as a superior alternative.

Comment: Got it working!

Created two executables (terminal command's), That i can call with a keyboard shortcut.

This really save's me so much time! Many thanks!

Comment: `voices` still works in High Sierra, but sometimes fails to restart the Speech Synthesis Server. I did not look in to why, but removed lines 512-517 of `voices` and now use [this](https://bitbucket.org/nJGL/public/src/master/shellscripts/speak.sh) shell script to switch between languages from command line using `voices`by @mklement0 . Even without actively restarting the Speech Synthesis Server, the modified `voices` works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cello for the tip: https://github.com/mklement0/voices

I created a small appleScript to change the voice

```
on run {}
    set changeVoiceToo to ""
    set currentVoice to do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH;" & "voices -b"

    if currentVoice is "Alex" then
        set changeVoiceToo to "Xander"
    else
        set changeVoiceToo to "Alex"
    end if

    do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; voices -d " & changeVoiceToo

    do shell script "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; say " & changeVoiceToo
    # display notification currentVoice sound name "Tink"
    display notification "Voice Change!" with title changeVoiceToo # sound name "Tink"
end run
```

I hope this is useful to somebody

Answer (score 0):

MAC OS 13 VENTURA:
This script lets you change language on Ventura, so that you can get the Siri voice on multiple languages.
Open automator -> Add run apple script -> Past the script and create an app.
Set your desired language on line 22. Make one copy of the script pr language

The script works by activating Voice over to navigate, so you have to deactivate the VoiceOver welcome screen for it to work correctly. On the first run you will be told that the app lacks permission to keystroke.
What you have to do is go to system settings, Privacy & Security -> Accessibility -> and turn on the app you created. Use the pluss sign and add it if it did not appear automatically.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set volume with output muted #Turns off the volume
    tell application "System Settings" to activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 96 using command down #CMD F5 activate voiceover
        delay 4 #waiting to load, increase if buggy
        key code 125 #DOWN ARROW Moves from apperance to Accessibility
        delay 1
        key code 48 #TAB Scroll Area 1
        delay 1
        key code 48 #TAB Scroll Area 2
        delay 1
        key code 48 #TAB Scroll Area 3
        delay 1
        key code 48 #TAB Scroll Area 4
        delay 1
        key code 49 #SPACE Entering Spoken Content Menu
        delay 1
        key code 49 #SPACE Entering System speech language MENU
        delay 1
        keystroke "English" #Choose your language. First letter is enoufgh like N for Norwegian.
        delay 1
        key code 36 #ENTER Selects the language
        delay 1
        key code 96 using command down #de-activate voiceover   
        delay 1
        tell application "System Settings" to quit
        delay 3
        set volume without output muted #Turn the volume back on
    end tell
    return input
end run
```